# SSRS - Ordered list breaking mid list and starting over

Tags: html, reporting-services, tags, html-lists, ssrs-2012

While working with SSRS, I seem to be having an issue with my ordered list.  The string the report is pulling in from the database follows this format:

```
<ol>
    <li>First listed item</li>
    <li>Second listed item</li>
    <li>Third listed item with subset:
      <ol>
        <li>Third listed, 1st subset</li>
        <li>Third listed, 2nd subset</li>
      </ol>"Random notes here"
    </li>
    <li>Fourth listed item with subset:
      <ol>
        <li>Fourth listed, 1st subset</li>  
        <li>Fourth listed, 2nd subset</li>
        <li>Fourth listed, 3rd subset</li>
      </ol>"Another random note here"
        </li>
    <li>Fifth listed item
    </li>
</ol>
```

The issue that I seem to be having is that when it gets the the 'Fourth listed item', the numbering starts over with number 1 instead of being number 4.  The placeholder properties that presents this data does have the 'HTML - Interpret html tags as styles' selected.  When I get a simple html file with the code above, it looks correct, but when the report renders it, it restarts the counting.  I'm not sure what's causing the report to do this.

Comment: HTML support in SSRS is not great but I surprised that it breaks at that point. Have you tried examining the rendered output from your browser and see what the final HTML looks like? That might give you a clue.

Comment: @AlanSchofield yes, I created a quick, small HTML file with the my code and it orders the list just fine.  No restarting of the count.

Comment: I meant when the report is on screen, hit F12 in the browser and look at the actual HTML that has been generated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to placing your additional content without `<li></li>` tag inside the `<ol></ol>` tag.

In regular HTML we won't place a text inside `<ol></ol>` tag, But in SSRS it's triky to get our desired output. Check below HTML code.

```
<ol>
        <li>First listed item</li>
        <li>Second listed item</li>
        <li>Third listed item with subset:
          <ol>
              <li>Third listed, 1st subset</li>
              <li>Third listed, 2nd subset</li>
              "Random notes here"              
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Fourth listed item with subset:
          <ol>
              <li>Fourth listed, 1st subset</li>
              <li>Fourth listed, 2nd subset</li>
              <li>Fourth listed, 3rd subset</li>
             "Another random note here" 
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Fifth listed item
        </li>
    </ol>
```